# How can I align images next to inputs with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a user login page for my webapp but I'm looking to have the username image and the username input next to each other. It was alright but now can not get it inline again.

I know it is a mess but does anyone see the problem here? I'm more of a back-end developer...

I have tried inline command but it seems to mess with the styling.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: box-sizing: border-box;
  ;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "segoe ui", roboto, oxygen, ubuntu, cantarell, "fira sans", "droid sans", "helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
  background-color: #435165;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.login {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 1px auto;
  width: 360px;
  height: min-content;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.login h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #5b6574;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee0e4;
}

.login form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.login form label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3274d6;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.login form input[type="password"],
.login form input[type="text"] {
  width: 310px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

.login form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #3274d6;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.login form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #2868c7;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->

<div class="login">
  <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>

  <form action="authenticate.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group was-validated">
      <label class="form-label" for="username">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      </label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group was-validated">
      <label class="form-label" for="password">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
      </label>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" required>
    </div>
    
    <input class="btn btn-success w-100" type="submit" value="Enter">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version. That's critical information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox property,

#### Step 1

```css
.login form .form-group {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  gap: .25rem;
}
```

#### Step 2

```css
.login form input[type="password"],
.login form input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%; /* instead of 310px */
  ...
  ...
  ...
}
```

#### Demo

```css
* {
  box-sizing: box-sizing: border-box;
  ;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "segoe ui", roboto, oxygen, ubuntu, cantarell, "fira sans", "droid sans", "helvetica neue", Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

body {
  background-color: #435165;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.login {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 9px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  margin: 1px auto;
  width: 360px;
  height: min-content;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.login h1 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #5b6574;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dee0e4;
}

.login form {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.login form label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #3274d6;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.login form input[type="password"],
.login form input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #dee0e4;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  padding: 0 15px;
  
}

.login form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: #3274d6;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.login form input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background-color: #2868c7;
  transition: background-color 0.2s;
}

.login form .form-group {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  gap: .25rem;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> -->

<div class="login">
  <h1 class="text-center">Login</h1>

  <form action="authenticate.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group was-validated">
      <label class="form-label" for="username">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
      </label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group was-validated">
      <label class="form-label" for="password">
        <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
      </label>
      <input class="form-control" type="password" id="password" required>
    </div>
    
    <input class="btn btn-success w-100" type="submit" value="Enter">
  </form>
</div>
```